# stop scroller for particular page in jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, vue.js, laravel-5.3

I m new to vue please help me.I had created a landing page in vue using scrollTop & jquery easing plugin

```
$(function() {
$('.navbar-nav a').bind('click', function(event) {
    debugger
    var $anchor = $(this);
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top - 0
    }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
    event.preventDefault();
  });
});

$(window).on('load', function () {
     $('.status').fadeOut();
     $('.preloader').delay(350).fadeOut('slow');
 });

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
   wow = new WOW(
        {
        animateClass: 'animated',
        offset: 100,
        mobile: true
        }
      );
  wow.init();
});
```

[image: demo image link]
now when user click on pricing then it move down to pricing section of same landing page

here is my question, now when user click on login page then it move to new page . because of this above jquery. it throw error  (Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #/login) beacuse above jquery searching for #login in same page but i want to treat this login page as new (i.e above jquery will disable for this login nav)
here is my vue component header nav

```
         <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExample07">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#how-it-work">How it work</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#features">Features</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#pricing">Pricing</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#faq">FAQ</a>
                    </li>
                     <li class="nav-item">
                      <router-link :to='"/login"' class="nav-link" exact> Login</router-link>
                     </li>
                </ul>

            </div>
```

Comment: If I understand what you are trying to do, you won't be able to do it with jQuery.   Have a look at  the docs for vue-router scroll-behavior here https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/scroll-behavior.html

Comment: @skribe then how i can create in vue any example

Comment: I upvoted your question, hopefully someone else will answer.   Honestly I have never tried to use jQuery in such a way with Vue or Vue router since the same functionality is available natively. You might want to add vue-router to your questions tags